# Custom Aggregation on Fields in Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame like:

```
time    action    value
--------------------------
10:00   FG        2
10:00   Ast       0
09:45   Miss      0
09:40   TO        0
09:40   Steal     0
09:30   FG        2
09:30   FT        1
```

I would like to group this off `time`, but in two different ways:

- `action` should be turned into a list
- `value` should be summed up

Expected output:

```
time    action    value
--------------------------
10:00   [FG,Ast]  2
09:45   Miss      0
09:40   [TO,Steal]0
09:30   [FG,FT]   3
```

I am able to do them each individually:

- list: `df.groupby('time')['action'].apply(list).reset_index()`
- sum: `df.groupby('action')['value'].sum()

How can I do these both together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby.agg` :

```
df = df.groupby('time', as_index=False).agg({'action':list, 'value':np.sum})

print(df)
    time       action  value
0  09:30     [FG, FT]      3
1  09:40  [TO, Steal]      0
2  09:45       [Miss]      0
3  10:00    [FG, Ast]      2
```